# Fill image map on click and set variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image map of a human body that I have separated out into 3 zones (for simplicity): body, right leg, and left leg.

I want to be able to click the section of the body, and have that section change colors (ex. fill gray) and set the value of a variable to true (1) for that section. All body sections are by default a value 0.

Variables that need to be set are

- {Hidden:TORSO}
- {Hidden:RLEG}
- {Hidden:LLEG}

Here is my image map:

```
<img src="http://imgur.com/wzHgrvS.jpg" usemap="#Map" border="0" />

<map name="Map"map id="bodyMap" name="myMap" >
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="Torso" href="#" id="TORSO" coords="94,84,95,134,107,177,104,189,102,200,103,209,102,221,188,220,184,197,182,183,183,168,187,153,191,142,192,129,188,89,155,90,130,90,114,89" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="Right Leg" href="#"id="RLEG" coords="99,221,97,242,94,259,90,270,90,291,91,315,94,333,96,343,95,347,94,358,93,366,93,372,89,387,89,405,93,421,96,439,99,456,100,470,100,477,116,477,113,462,116,441,119,423,122,408,119,392,117,376,122,363,126,337,133,314,139,289,140,273,133,265,130,252,122,240,114,231" />
<area shape="poly" alt="" title="Left Leg" href="#" id="LLEG" coords="147,269,153,303,158,319,162,338,164,348,164,357,166,365,170,373,170,380,168,391,166,403,166,414,168,427,172,443,174,460,175,469,174,474,190,473,187,453,192,437,194,423,199,399,197,381,195,349,191,335,196,315,196,289,196,265,191,242,189,222,187,218,176,230,167,239,160,249,155,262,154,266,148,270" />
</map>
```

I have done this with  and selecting a hotspot on an image i.e. circles on a part of a body, but never the whole limb. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the fastest/easiest way to do this is with the [ImageMapster jQuery plugin](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/).

ImageMapster (GitHub: jamietre / ImageMapster, License: MIT) by James Treworgy makes it easier to manipulate HTML image maps. Interesting effects can be created using image maps and more modern HTML/CSS/JavaScript techniques, while still falling over to the basic functionality in older browsers.

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/

These demos show that it will do exactly what you desire:

http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html

By calling `$('img').mapster(options)`, ImageMapster will attempt to bind to each image that has an associated map. An area within the image map can be selected with `$('area').mapster('select')`. The project has lots of options and features.

Here is code for a somewhat basic example:

http://jsfiddle.net/nYkAG/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had been trying to figure out mapster a little earlier, but didn't succeed at doing anything useful. Since I saw your reply yesterday, I have looked over a number of demos and their documentation, but I can't get mine to work. I'm a bit of a noob at JS, would you mind taking a look at mine? I've followed just about all of his demos and tried to no avail: http://jsfiddle.net/Cd6Cz/

Comment: I'm not that great with ImageMapster, although I've used it for a couple of projects. It has worked great, once I've gotten it to work (usually with SO help). I suggest that you post exactly the question you have above, with that fiddle, into a new question (ensure you use both jQuery and imagemapster tags) and I'm sure you'll have it answered within a half hour. Best wishes!

Answer (score 0):

What you'll need to do is use is create image maps for those areas that you want to click and have something happen. If you don't have Photoshop or Firework and are looking for a free service, try [Image-Maps.com](http://www.image-maps.com/upload.php).

Comment: I have image maps for those areas in the code above...I included 3 areas, that's not the question I'm asking. I want to click on those areas and have them fill with a color and set a hidden variable to value 1

Comment: In that case you will need to add some JavaScript; a jQuery plugin is probably best/easiest. Maphighlight or ImageMapster both come to mind: http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/ | http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/